# Cannot Resume after suspending Ubuntu 12.04, using Thinkpad T420S

Tags: suspend

I am aware that similar questions have been posted, and believe me, I have tried a lot of the solutions, but nothing works for me.  So I think my case might just be special and deserves a new post.

I'm using Thinkpad T420s, with NVIDIA NVS 4200M graphics card.  I installed Ubuntu 12.04 as soon as it came out, but Suspend never worked properly.  When I try to resume my computer after suspending it, I just get a lit but black screen.  The only thing I'm able to do is to turn off the machine using power button.

At first I thought that's an Ubuntu issue, so I tried Mint instead.  However, I was surprised that I met the same problem using Mint: the screen just remains black after being resumed from suspend!

I tried installing pm-utils as many suggested, but it didn't work.  I tried installing laptop-mode-tools as many suggested, but it didn't work.  I tried installing NVIDIA driver, but it didn't work (weird that I couldn't see any driver in "Additional Drivers" even though I installed the NVIDIA driver).  So now I have no idea what to do and am here asking for help.

Thanks a lot for reading this!  Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You might be having problems with your hard drive power managment.
I have had A LOT of troubles with Ubuntu suspension/resuming, and also tried all of the things you mentioned. Another thing I tried was reconfiguring the hard drive's power managment.

You can try editing "/etc/laptop-mode/laptop-mode.conf" from this:

```
# Power management for HD (hdparm -B values)
#
BATT_HD_POWERMGMT=1
```

To this:

```
# Power management for HD (hdparm -B values)
#
#BATT_HD_POWERMGMT=1
BATT_HD_POWERMGMT=254
LM_AC_HD_POWERMGMT=254
NOLM_AC_HD_POWERMGMT=254
```

It might help. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for help!  Did that work for you?