# Unable to resume after suspend -- 15.04

Tags: 15.04, suspend

I'm using Ubuntu for the first time on my laptop, and everything is fine except that whenever I suspend the system (either manually or by closing the lid) and then resume, I get a completely black screen which forces me to do a hard reset. I tried running `pm-suspend --quirk-s3-mode`, but when I resumed from that it displayed the screen I had before pressing enter, only it was completely frozen and no key-combos would break it. I've tried searching for solutions, but they've all been for previous versions of Ubuntu. Here are my specs (don't know what's relevant, will add what's necessary):

- Laptop: Lenovo Z50-70
- Kernel: Linux 3.19.0-28-generic
- Display: GF117M with nouveau driver

EDIT: I just tried `sudo pm-suspend --quirk-vbemode-restore` with the same results as s3-mode. I got an error report on reboot which I submitted, but I don't know where to pull that up so that I can copy it.

Things I've tried:

- Locking screen, closing lid, then opening and resuming (black screen)
- Running `pm-suspend` in virtual console (resumes to virtual console, but frozen)
- Switching to a proprietary driver and trying the above again (same problems)

EDIT2: Working through the top answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/361547/ubuntu-freezes-crash-after-wake-when-upgraded-to-13-10) (though `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pcie_aspm=force"` hasn't worked) and then trying [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/171479/cannot-resume-after-suspending-ubuntu-12-04-using-thinkpad-t420s?rq=1)

EDIT3: [Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQzRp.png)

Comment: Previous versions are always helpful, as long as they're not _too_ old. For instance, a fix for 12.04 or 13.04 will probably work for 14.04 or 15.04, whereas something for 9.10 probably won't have any results on 14.04.

Comment: I tried what was offered [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/436133/unable-to-resume-after-suspend?rq=1) but I wasn't able to use the virtual console on resume and ended up having to hard reset again...

Comment: Any fix for this yet? I'm having similar problems, except suspending just seems to break the window manager. All the windows turn black and smear across the desktop when I move or resize them...

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution but another workaround:

If you are using the nvidia card you should switch to the intel one before the suspension, that worked for me (i'm using the proprietary drivers instead of the nouveau ones but i think that should work on your configuration too).

Someone in other posts, like [yarrok](https://askubuntu.com/users/443974/yarrok) said, suggests to make a bash script that intercepts the suspension and switches to a virtual console before suspending and switches again on the x-session on restore automatically, but that hasn't worked for me.
However, if you find out how to switch your video driver programmatically you could use the same trick to switch it automatically before the suspension and restore it on resume.

The only thing that concerns me is that probably when you switch video driver you have to logout to apply the change.